# 2D Pathfinding in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, path-finding

I am looking for a way to include a mechanism just like the Navmesh Agents into a 2D scenario. In the szenario, 2D objects move on a flat sprite surface. In some cases, they need to reach each other which would be best achived with a path finding algorithm. As I could not find a solution online (Navmesh seems to be only available for 3D objects), I would be thankful for a hint where to start.
As an additional question: would applying these pathfinding algorithms on +100 objects at once cause severe performance problems on mobile devices? If so - are there alternatives? Right now I just delete the collider, if a timer passes and the two targets did not reach each other. This however, leads to heavy visual clutter with a lot of elements on the surface.

[image]

Greetings,

Codehai

Comment: You can use [A* Pathfinding Project](https://arongranberg.com/astar/docs/pathfinding-2d.php) package for Unity. Download [link](https://arongranberg.com/astar/download)

Answer (score 1):

1. I'm pretty sure you can use the built-in 3D system for that
2. Simply visit the asset store to instantly find solutions to "2D pathfinding"

[image]

3. As Ehsan mentions, google for many solutions, eg

https://arongranberg.com/astar/docs/pathfinding-2d.php

[image]

Comment: We both had the idea to comment on a 2 year old post just 10 seconds between each other :-P

Comment: dohhhh !  thanks @Codehai !  Man, I hate the "OLD POST SURPRISE"  Geesh.

Answer (score 1):

As the comment suggest, A* Pathfinding Project may be a valid option.
However I ended up using https://github.com/h8man/NavMeshPlus for price/performance reasons.
h8man did an excellent job transfering the 3D Navmesh functions to the 2D environment - I wonder how long it takes before Unity devs will integrate this themselves.