# how to create a path that when blocked it follows another path that is predefined

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, path-finding

I'm using unity2d to create a map for a fnaf prototype and I want a enemy to follow a predetermined path
but when I close a door on the map I want it to use another predetermined path  and repeat that for all other paths until the last path then  go back to the start but I have no idea what the best way to go about this is I was thinking if and else statements but i would think there is like a tool or something to help do that? So to sum it all up:** I want to make a path following enemy that when blocked uses another path and want to know the best way to do it or if there is tools to do this in unity2d **

I tried to use if and else statements but that got pretty messy and my code got all jumbled

Comment: [2D A* pathfinding in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52026412/2d-pathfinding-in-unity)

Comment: What do you mean with "repeat that for all other paths"?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a graph of all your possible predefined paths, and set the cost of the preferred path lower than the alternative paths. If you close the door you would then change the cost of that node to infinite, forcing the enemy to take the alternative route. You could then use something like A* or Djikstra to find the correct path to follow, this should be fairly cheep unless the number of nodes is very large.

If you use a cost function that uses the maximum of any visited note you can simply assign a cost of zero to the preferred path, one to the first alternative, 2 to the second etc. That way the number of nodes visited is irrelevant, only the preferred order to take.